# Узнать ID (AUTO_INCREMENT)

Tags: mysql, mysqli, php, sql

Здравствуйте. Есть некий запрос MySQL:

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `test_table` (`name`) VALUES ('test')");
```

Структура таблицы test_table: `ID(AUTO_INCREMENT)`, `name`.

То есть при данном запросе id будет установлен автоматически.  
Как мне его узнать?  
То есть мне нужно узнать Id, который был установлен.

Comment: SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();

Comment: а если необходимо просто узнать значение Авто_Инкремента, без всяких дополнительных действий?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.insert-id.php - вот ^_^.
Возвращает последний ИД.

Answer (score 3):

http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.insert-id.php